# web2py join tables from different database

Tags: database, join, web2py

looking for help .
I use web2py , and my app require multiple databases .
for example two database :

```
db1 = DAL('sqlite://first.sqlite')
db2 = DAL('sqlite://second.sqlite')
```

with tables :

```
db1.define_table('table1',
                Field('id',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('pid',type='integer'),
                Field('title',type='string'),
                 )
```

and

```
db2.define_table('table2',
                Field('id',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('pid',type='integer'),
                Field('data',type='string'),
                 )
```

How to execute sqlite join ,something like:

```
sql ="SELECT db1.id, db1.title,db2.data FROM db1.table1 INNER JOIN db2.table2 ON db2.table2.pid == db1.table1.pid"
```

db1.executesql(sql) doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do joins with tables from different DAL instances.
Also, each DAL instance can only connect to one database.

Using two DAL instances you can do two separate selects and combine them programmatically, using operators | or & with the resultant R

```
>>> print rows1
person.name
Max
Tim
>>> print rows2
person.name
John
Tim

>>> rows3 = rows1 & rows2
>>> print rows3
name
Tim
```

But this will cost you more processing time.